# How to find an object within an array list?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

This is what i have done so far with parameter of two integer and two string. I Added the object string in the array list. For the method, whenever i typed in the correct id, the system supposed to print out the painting name. The system did worked for the first part only which is when i typed in 1440 however when i typed in other id like 1441 or 1442 the system doesn't show the painting name

```
public PintBook()
    {
        Painting = new Array List <Painting>();`enter code here`
    }

    public void add(int id, String name,String artist,String minibidprice)
    {
        Painting.add (new Painting(id,name,artist,minibidprice));
    }
```

After that i put in the object

```
PintBook p = new PintBook();
p.add(1440,"Water-Lillies","Claude Monet","$10,000.00");
p.add(1441,"Flowers in a Blue Vase ","Paul Cezanne","$20,000.00");
p.add(1442,"The Anglers","Henri Rousseau ","$50,000.00");
p.add(1443,"Wild Potato Dreaming","Emily Kngwarreye","$45,000.00");
p.add(1446,"Argenteuil","Claude Monet ","$100,000.00");
p.add(1447,"Luncheon on the Grass","Paul Cezanne","$50,000.00");
p.add(1448,"Antonia","Amadeo Modigliani ","$30,000.00");
```

Purpose for below coding is that to print out the second string name when the correct id is typed in

```
    public void id()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Painting ID : ");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        for (Painting e : Painting){
            if(id==e.getID()){
               System.out.println("found");
               System.out.println(e.getPaintingName());

            }else{
                System.out.println("not found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

when i typed in 1440 it shows that

```
1440
found
Water Lillie
```

However When i typed other correct id numbers it doesnt show the second string name. i dont know where i did wrong. 
    Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the program just end after it loops one time instead of asking for another id? Also your break; should be removed or the loop will end after going through the first item.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break;` statement is in the wrong place, move it to the if branch (when id's match).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if the first element of the list hasnt the id you are searching for you break the loop.

```
if(id==e.getID()){
    System.out.println("found");
    System.out.println(e.getPaintingName());
}
else
    System.out.println("not found");
    break;
}
```

Do it like this

```
boolean found = false;
for (Painting e : Painting) {
    if(id==e.getID()){
       System.out.println("found");
       System.out.println(e.getPaintingName());
       found = true;
       break;
    }
}
if(!found){
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Comment: Totally works .You are right sir. I took your advice and changed my code as yours.

Comment: @user3445104 Glad to hear that. Then please accept the answer which suits best to help other to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void printfindings(int id){

    for (Painting e : Painting)

    {
        if(id==e.getID()){
           System.out.println("found");
           System.out.println(e.getPaintingName());

            break;


            }
        else
            System.out.println("not found");

    }
    }}
```

Comment: This will result in multiple Sysout's of "not found" if the element is not on first position.

Comment: Totally works, I really appreciate your answer Mr Danial

Comment: tick answer so that in future people get solution.

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration of for loop, break is called, no matter if the id was found or not. Break should be at the end of "if" clause.